# Unable to save Integer using NSUserDefaults while exiting the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nsuserdefaults

I an a beginner wanting to to store an int value (high score) in my app so when the user closes the app from the multitasking and opens it again it will get the data and display it.

I tried using NSUserDefaults, but it does not appear when I open the app again. Here is the code I used:

```
// Used this to load the high score from the memory
  highscoreInt = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highscore"]; 

// And this to store it, later in the code
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highscoreInt forKey:@"highscore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in `applicationWillTerminate:` to make sure the integer was stored?

Comment: What you mean by not working ? Is it always showing same value ?

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is called when the app is going to be purged from memory. In other words, if you put your app to the background, then back to the foreground, this method is not called. Consider using `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillResignActive` to store your score. To confirm this, just set a breakpoint on the first line in `applicationWillTerminate`, simulate background/foreground and you'll see that your app will not be paused (breakpoint hit).

Comment: "in Xcode"? are you sure it's "in Xcode" and not, rather, in your iOS app?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. As stated in the question, I am a beginner, so my ways are not too professional. 
When I say it is not working, I mean that when I re-open my app the value is reseted and yes, it is in my iOS app. 
I also don't know what 'setting a breakpoint' is, so I did not do so.

Thank you again for all your comments!

Comment: just click at the left side of the line you want to add breakpoint, and after you run the code, if the code stops and the line is highlighted where you added the breakpoint, means you code is getting executed else not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the integer in an `NSNumber` object, and put this in `applicationDidEnterBackground` like so:

```
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, 
// invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to 
// restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  highscoreInt = (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highscore"]; 

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScoreInt] forKey:@"highscore"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

When you need to load your score, do the following inside whatever method you want to load it in:

```
int highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"highscore"];
```

You'll find this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) helpful when reading up on `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Thank you! How would it be to load the high score?

Comment: I tried it, but I get the following warning and it doesn't work: 'Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'id __nullable'

Comment: @CelceCode Make sure you're not saying int* instead of int. Somewhere, you're trying to convert a pointer to a primitive data type.

Answer (score 1):

Use **NSInteger** instead of int

```
NSInteger highScore=0;
```

To store it

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

and to get it back

```
NSInteger highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Comment: This has proven to be the best method, as I get no errors, but it won't work either

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend saving the high score whenever it changes.

Comment: That's how I did it. Thanks!